# Read csv but skip escaped commas in strings

Tags: r, file, readr

I have a csv file like this:

```
id,name,value
 1,peter,5
 2,peter\,paul,3
```

How can I read this file and tell R that `"\,"` does not indicate a new column, only `","`.

I have to add that file has 400mb.

Thanks

Comment: use read.csv and sep=","  , something like this df <- read.csv("path to your file /df.csv", sep =",")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `readLines()` to read the file into memory and then pre-process it. If you're willing to convert the non-separate commas into something else, you can do something like:

```
> read.csv(text = gsub("\\\\,", "-", readLines("dat.csv")))
  id       name value
1  1      peter     5
2  2 peter-paul     3
```

Another option is to utilize the fact that the `fread` function from data.table can perform system commands as its first argument. Then you can do something like a `sed` operation on the file before reading it in (which may or may not be faster):

```
> data.table::fread("sed -e 's/\\\\\\,/-/g' dat.csv")
   id       name value
1:  1      peter     5
2:  2 peter-paul     3
```

You can always then use `gsub()` to convert the temporary `-` separator back into a comma.

Comment: thanks. The first solution is too slow for huge files, I had to abort after 4+ hours. The second one fails when it encouters a line with an observation like this:   123,time=\\,5. Error is ``Expected sep (',') but new line or EOF ends field 3 on line 987841 when reading data:``

Comment: @spore234 You should be able to modify the sed expression to allow multiple slashes, perhaps with: `"sed -e 's/\\\\\\+,/-/g' dat.csv"`